# how to get a string from span element using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

i have used ajax to get set of values from server and displayed using span.span display so many contents,but from that i want to select only one content from the list.

```
var z=document.getElementById("spanOutput").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
```

response from server like:

content 1

content 2

content 3

So I want to select **content 2** from span element and need to displayed on the browser. How to achieve this?

Comment: Please make an example on a service such as jsbin.com. Your question is unclear.

Comment: You response is plain text or it has some sort of struture?

Comment: Can you make this a bit more clear? Do you have in the same span "content 1   content 2    content 3" all together? What does separates the content 1 with the content 2? Just a break line? Is there any chance you are going to have a break line in any of the contents? We will require more info...

Comment: Content 1,content 2 and so on are simply text or some kind of html element ?

Answer (score 1):

Define a Array to save these span contents.

```
var arr=[];
for(var i=0; i<document.getElementById("spanOutput").getElementsByTagName("span").length;i++)
{
arr.push(document.getElementById("spanOutput").getElementsByTagName("span")[i]);
}
```

comtent 2 will be arr[ 1 ]

Answer (score 0):

Use value property:

```
var z = document.getElementById("spanOutput").value;
document.getElementById("spanOutput").value = xmlhttp.responseText;
```

Comment: i just want to select only few text.not the whole span content